# Doing summation and multiplication with different shapes matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an N*M matrix A and a N-length vector V. I want to do A + V where each element in a row i of A is summed with the element i in V. How to do that?

e.g.:

```
A = np.random.rand(3,2)
V = np.array([1,2,3])
A + V

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3)
```

I want to do the same with multiplication and division.

Comment: Your example is not correct; `a` and `v` are not defined.  Could you please edit that?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
V = V.reshape(-1,1)
A + V
```

now this works

Answer (score 0):

The concept to look up here is [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It enables you to have pointwise interaction between any two matrices as long as their shapes correspond or, on the axes without correspondence, at least one of the sides is degenerate, i.e. of size `1`. In your case, you need to add an axis to V. One can do this elegantly as follows

```
A + V[:, np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell numpy it has to extend the dimensions of the vector `V` by one, and you can do it using the special index `np.newaxis`. It would look like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[10,20],[100,200],[1000,2000]])
V = np.array([1,2,3])
A + V[:,np.newaxis]

array([[  11,   21],
       [ 102,  202],
       [1003, 2003]])
```

From the [slicing docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Each newaxis object in the selection tuple serves to expand the dimensions of the resulting selection by one unit-length dimension. The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.